# In dbeaver call procedure execution is not showing output even after i open ctrl+shift+o window

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I am using Dbeaver for postgre sql and I have not been able to execute call procedure after successful compilation. When I execute call procedure it shows in script successfully but not in the output window.

I have already checked that sql editor setting where open output viewer on new messages tick box is enabled.
even after i press ctrl+shift+o the output window shows nothing.

Comment: This needs more detail. What output do you expect from a procedure?

Comment: wanted to print a message using raise notice.

Comment: Does the server output console show the message if you create and call a procedure that does only `raise notice 'test';` and nothing else? What do you get when you run [`show client_min_messages;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES)?

Comment: Yes, looks like you cannot get that with DBeaver.

Comment: when i just run a procedure with only raise notice  it still shows nothing, output window does not open and even after i open output console there is nothing. just emty box with search bar thats all. When i run show client_min_messages; it returns notice

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in DBeaver version 23.2.5.

The filter options of that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> output window match message severity levels but in version 23.2.5 it never reports anything except transaction debug info if you do [`set client_min_messages=debug5;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) - not even if you `raise debug 'sth';` yourself.

If you want that to work, you'll have to downgrade. I've checked it works fine in [23.2.4](https://dbeaver.io/files/23.2.4/) and earlier. You can test other versions with the script below:

```sql
show client_min_messages;
set client_min_messages=notice;
show client_min_messages;

do $$
begin
    raise notice using hint = 'notice hint', message = 'notice message', detail='notice detail';
    raise warning using hint = 'warning hint', message = 'warning message', detail='warning detail';
    raise debug using hint = 'debug hint', message = 'debug message', detail='debug detail';
    raise log using hint = 'log hint', message = 'log message', detail='log detail';
    raise info using hint = 'info hint', message = 'info message', detail='info detail';
end $$;
```

Looks like the issue has already been reported [here](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/21902).

Comment: Thanks. In older version it is working fine.